# How to change audio device in ALSA without pulseaudio and need for restart

Tags: sound, alsa

After struggling with pulseaudio issues that I could not happen to resolve I decided to revert back to alsa with a simple sudo apt-get purge pulseaudio.

This works great for me, however changing the default device to my USB headsets is a struggle as I want to switch them more than set a default for an entire session.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I am currently using at the moment is changing the default device by creating the .asoundrc file in my home folder and adding the code:`pcm.!default {type hw card 2}`

I know to specify card 2 from the output when I run: `aplay -l`

The output looks like this for me:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 0: ALC892 Analog [ALC892 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: SB [HDA ATI SB], device 1: ALC892 Digital [ALC892 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Headset [Cyborg F.R.E.Q.5 Gaming Headset], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

After this I reload alsa with: `sudo alsa reload`

Programs that are running still need to be restarted for me, however, but it's a start.

I use this odd script to swap between my two cards:

```
#!/bin/bash
currentSound=`cat currentSound`
if [ "$currentSound" == "0" ]; then
    echo "pcm.!default { type hw card 2}" > ~/.asoundrc
    echo "2" > currentSound
    echo "2"
else 
    echo "pcm.!default { type hw card 0}" > ~/.asoundrc
    echo "0" > currentSound
    echo "0"
fi
sudo alsa reload
```

It creates a file that it uses to know what it needs to swap to next.

It's not seamless like with pulseaudio but it's all I've been able to come up with so far.